# Function object as template parameter

Tags: c++, function-object

```
template <typename elemType, typename Comp = less<elemType> >
class LessThanPred {
    public:
        LessThanPred(const elemType &val) : _val(val){}
        bool operator()(const elemType &val) const
        { return Comp(val, _val); }
        void val(const elemType &newval) { _val = newval; }
        elemType val() const { return _val; }
private:
    elemType _val;};
```

That's an example from Essential c++. `Comp` is obviously a function object class name. Why could I use the `Comp(val, _val)` directly? Normally I think I should firstly define a function object like this: `Comp comp`, then invoke `comp` not `Comp`.

Comment: Comp is a type parameter, not a function object class name. By the way, you can actually define a `Comp comp` object and then invoke `comp`.

Comment: Did you instantiate/use the function call operator of `LessThanPred`? Since it is a template member it gets checked for correctly only when instantiated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The citation is not correct

Comment: @DieterLücking: section 6.7 "Template Parameters as Strategy" of "Essential C++" (1st printing) does contain that exact code.

Comment: Hence I am wrong (wtf, trusting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as is compiles because the template members are only checked for semantic correctness when they are instantiated. The code is syntactically well-formed, though. However, when you try to instantiate the function call operator of `LessThanPred<T>`, you'll get a compiler error. For example, with the version of [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/) (3.6.1) I'm using I get

```
less-than.cpp:8:18: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::less<int>'
        { return Comp(val, _val); }
                 ^    ~~~~~~~~~
less-than.cpp:17:25: note: in instantiation of member function 'LessThanPred<int, std::less<int> >::operator()' requested here
    LessThanPred<int>(2)(1);
```

when trying to use the function as

```
LessThanPred<int>(2)(1)
```

Comment: For the default situation, could I change the code ' { return Comp(val, _val); }' into  { return Comp()(val, _val); }?